# Spring: MethodInvokingFactoryBean calls wrong method

Tags: java, xml, spring, methods

I need to do the following Java line in XML:

```
usersConnectionRepository.setConnectionSignUp(new AccountConnectionSignUp());
```

So I did this:

```
<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="accountConnectionSignUp" class="edu.kit.tm.cm.ksc.config.AccountConnectionSignUp" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="usersConnectionRepository" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>setConnectionSignUp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref local="accountConnectionSignUp" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The error occurs when the method is supposed to be called.

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.setConnectionSignUp(edu.kit.tm.cm.ksc.config.AccountConnectionSignUp)
```

As you can see above, it's totally searching in the wrong package, and I have no idea why.

I have no idea how to debug this further. I'm inexperienced with Spring and it's XML-Notation. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

### UPDATE

As requested, the complete social.xml. Although, I do not think it is needed to solve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter"
xmlns:social="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-twitter.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/social http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:/edu/kit/tm/cm/ksc/config/application.properties" />


<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumerKey}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumerSecret}" />
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>



<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="accountConnectionSignUp" class="edu.kit.tm.cm.ksc.config.AccountConnectionSignUp" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="usersConnectionRepository" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>setConnectionSignUp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref local="accountConnectionSignUp" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
    factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
    <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />


<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
    <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" /> -->
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="connectionRepository" /> -->
</bean>


<bean id="SimpleSignInAdapter" class="edu.kit.tm.cm.ksc.config.SimpleSignInAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
    <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
    <constructor-arg ref="SimpleSignInAdapter" />
</bean>
```

### Update 2

We wrote the Java-examples of the [Spring-Social-Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.M4/reference/html/signin.html#d4e846) to XML. In this case for the ProviderSigninControllers dependencies. Unfortunately there are no XML examples given in this case.

Comment: Post the rest of your context configuration.

Comment: You're sending a value, don't you need to send a ref? Not sure what you mean by searching the wrong package, have you been confused by the proxy instead?

Comment: The method I want to call is in the usersConnectionRepository, which is a part of Spring and not in com.sun.... so I thought it's searching in the wrong package. I did not think about the proxy and I honestly have no idea what it means. Anyway, the Exception indicates that it can't find this method. Yes a ref would be better, thats right. Did not think about that. The error changed a bit. I'll add this and more into the question.  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.setConnectionSignUp(edu.kit.tm.cm.ksc.config.AccountConnectionSignUp)

Comment: Is there a version difference between you spring jars. Seems the JdbcConnectionRepository class has no setConnectionSignUp method which accepts your signup type.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need scoped proxy for singleton beans? Spring documentation suggests you shouldn't even be able to do it.

Comment: AccountConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp, so I think it should work, shouldn't it? It seems like removing the scoped proxy did remove the error! I have no idea why it was in there. We are working in a team of 6 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to change `proxy-target-class` to true in your `usersConnectionRepository` bean definition and add CGLIB to your class path.

If you don't need the proxying, remove it completely.

Explanation:

First, with this bean declaration

```
<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

Spring is creating a bean of type `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository` and wrapping it in a JDK proxy (since `proxy-target-class` is `false`). The serious shortcoming of JDK proxies, is that they only sub type interfaces.

In other words, Spring will see that the `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository` class implements the `UsersConnectionRepository` interface and use that when generating the Proxy. As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) says

> - A proxy class extends java.lang.reflect.Proxy.
> - A proxy class implements exactly the interfaces specified at its creation, in the
>     same order.

So the generated proxy will be of type `Proxy` and `UsersConnectionRepository`.

This won't be an issue for `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` because it stores the reference in a field of type `Object`. However, when `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` tries to resolve the `Method` to invoke, it uses the target object's `Class` instance, ie. `object.getClass()`. Since the target object is actually of type `Proxy`, or `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12` to be exact, it does not have a `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository#setConnectionSignUp` method and that causes a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: Thank you, an explantion would be awesome. It currently works when I remove it. It was probably supposed to be an equivalent of the "@Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)"-Annotation, which is supposed to be added to the java configuration according to the documentation.

Comment: @chocobai Please take a look and let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: Well, it explains the problem, but I'm not sure about the solution. According to the documentation I should create the Bean in java-annotation with a scoped proxy, meaning "@Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)". So how would I now write this in XML in a way the MethodInvoking still works?

Comment: @cho Can you link the document in question. There are many different ways yo do it. The document must be proposing one way.

Comment: It is proposing a way in Java-Notation only. I googled, but I only came to the same result as I wrote it before. I added the Link to the very bottom of my Question (Update 2). We set up Spring-Social using this Documentation.

Comment: @chocobai From reading part of the document, I'm still not exactly sure why they need a proxy, but let's take their word for it. If we want to keep the proxy, the solution, as I proposed, is to set `proxy-target-class` to `true` and add the CGLIB jar to the classpath.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really new at this. We're just students who have to improve a prototype and no one of us has much experience in java or spring. I googled quiet some time but I could not find any documentation or examples to this. Could you please explain how this has to be written into the XML file? And about the path, the only jar files I found are in the target directory. Like "/target/ksc-auth-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"... you mean it's one of those paths I have to write into the xml?

Comment: @chocobai [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) is a byte code manipulation library that Spring uses to generate proxies. You can get the latest version of the jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib). You need to download it and put it in the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory. You then change `proxy-target-class` to `true` in your XML context configuration for the `usersConnectionRepository` `<bean>` definition.